# Как осуществить запись и чтение настроек для гаджета?

Tags: гаджет, jquery, windows-7, html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Как осуществить сохранение настроек гаджета, и их своевременный вывод?

gadget.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hmtl>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script_gadg.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
            width: 260px;
            height: 240px;
            background: url(images/undockedBg.png);}
            div {
             font-family: Verdana;
             font-size: 8pt;
             color: white;
             padding: 10px 10px;
             }
        </style>
    </head>
<body onLoad="toDay();">
        <div id="day">Напоминалка</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

script_gadg.js:

```
function toDay()
{var name_day;
 var  day=(new Date()).getDay();
 initSettings();

 switch(day)
 {
      case 0:name_day="воскресенье";break;
      case 1:name_day="понедельник";break;
      case 2:name_day="вторник";break;
      case 3:name_day="среда";break;
      case 4:name_day="четверг";break;
      case 5:name_day="пятница";break;
      case 6:name_day="суббота";break;
 }
 document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = "Сегодня " + name_day;

}

function initSettings() 
{
    System.Gadget.settingsUI = 'settings.html';
}
```

setings.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="settings.js"></script>
    <style>
          body {
            width: 278px;
            height: 400px;
            }

          p {
            font-family: Verdana;
             font-size: 8pt;
             color: #990000;;
             padding: 10px 10px;
             }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    Понедельник<br>
    <input type="text" id="d1"><br>
    Вторник<br>
    <input type="text" id="d2"><br>
    Среда<br>
    <input type="text" id="d3"><br>
    Четверг<br>
    <input type="text" id="d4"><br>
    Пятница<br>
    <input type="text" id="d5"><br>
    Суббота<br>
    <input type="text" id="d6"><br>
    Воскресенье<br>
    <input type="text" id="d0">
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Никак не могу разобраться с этим делом... Много примеров посмотрел но ничего толком не понял... Сейчас гаджет выводит на экран день недели, хотелось бы чтоб ниже была строка в которой содержалась запись на сегодняшний день, эта запись задается в настройках.. Как осуществить запись и вывод настроек... Подскажите, будьте добры)

Рассмотрев примеры понял что дело в использование jquery, поэтому я подключил его к settings.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

и изменил файл settings.js в соответствие с этим:

settings.js

```
function settingsClosing(event) {
  if (event.closeAction == event.Action.commit) 
  {
    var d0 = $('#d0').val();
    if(!event.cancel)
     {
        System.Gadget.Settings.writeString('d0',d0);
      }
  }
}

function main()
 {
  System.Gadget.onSettingsClosing = settingsClosing;

  $('#d0').val(System.Gadget.Settings.readString('d0'));

  }

 $(document).ready(main);
```

Но при попытке открыть окно настроек, отладчик VS 2010 ругается на $(document).ready(main);

Как быть?...

Comment: Возможно в settings.js не определён document. Попробуйте ready в краткой записи: $(main);

Comment: Мммм нет все равно там же пишет "Ошибка выполнения Microsoft JScript: Предполагается наличие объекта"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы читали эту [инструкцию](http://kultin.ru/download/gadprog.pdf) о создании виджета для Win Vista, там автор довольно подробно описывает как сохранять и читать параметры

`System.Gadget.Settings.write("firstname", "John");`

Плюс можно попробовать посмотреть исходный код какого нибудь простого виджета, изменив расширение файла с .gadget на .zip и распаковав его (хотя это проходит не со всеми)

Comment: спасибо, конечно лучше поздно чем никогда, но я уже сам разобрался... и расширение не обязательно менять, winrar и так откроет) в общем все дело было в незнание jquery поэтому пришлось отказаться от него, и инструментами простого javascript'a после недолгих раздумий все получилось...